# Intento poner el valor actual de la tabla en el form

Tags: django, python-3.7, django-forms

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'numero'

Intento poner el valor que tengo en la tabla.

En Django forms estoy editando el contenido de la tabla.
Y quiero que por defecto aparezca en los inputs el valor actual.

forms.py

```
class InternalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    numero = forms.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Clientes
        fields = ('numero')

    def __init__(self, *args, instance=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, instance=instance, **kwargs)

        self.initial['numero'] = formats.number_format(instance.numero) #como no me entra en el if lo he puesto fuera y da este error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'numero'
        if instance:
             self.initial['numero'] = instance.numero # Lo estoy probando en 2 formas como no me funciona
        else:
             self.initial['numero'] = ''
```

¿Cómo debería hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en actions.py

en la clase de la acción donde llamas la función que te lleva al formulario creas esta función

```
def get_initial(self, request, queryset):
    initial_dict = {
        "numero": queryset.first().numero,
    }
    return initial_dict
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba totalmente equivocado